# Get value from richtextbox and assign them to radio button in c#?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm working on program that will take the input from richtextboxes in a loop and then I want to assign the text that I get from user to radiobutton that will be in a groupbox. I successfully developed the form with richtextboxes in a loop but now I stuck how I will assign them to radio button in a loop? When I click button?? Please guide me in this regard?

a piece of code here

```
Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 24);
                label1.Text = "Question" + _openCount++;
                label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
                richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 91);
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                Label label2 = new Label();
                label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 24);
                label2.Text = "Option1";
......................
```

now i want to put my code in this button how i further start my code???

```
void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: put your code within the two braces

Comment: You mean you want the text from the RTF control to appear as the button text? Just "button1.Text = richTectBox1.Text;".

Comment: but this only set richtextbox1 to button1 while i kept this textboxes in a array and it repeat according to last limit of array

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of your radio buttons, then create a list of your rich textbox strings.

Enumerable.Zip these two lists together then foreach through that list.

```
foreach(var item in zippedList)
{
    item.RadioButton.Text = item.RichTextBoxText.Text;
}
```

The syntax for this would be way off, but I hope you get the idea. This is also assuming that you have an equal number of radio buttons and lines of text. You'll need to take that into consideration and will have to modify the two lists before zipping them if they are different lengths.

Comment: thanks for your quick response and time.im new in c# not much knowledge about zipped list but must be searched. i put the richtextboxes in a loop e.g it run 4 times now i want the values of these 4 times running textboxes assigned to radiobutton will i have to use the foreach loop with other loop that 4 times??? please help me

Comment: Zipping is simply where you attach two rows of equal length together so you can foreach through both at the same time. It's like creating a list of tuples.

Comment: "e.g it run 4 times now i want the values of these 4 times running textboxes assigned to radiobutton will i have to use the foreach loop with other loop that 4 times" Could you please rephrase this? I have no idea what you're actually asking :\

Comment: imean i make a form in which i create one question and 4 options and put it in a loop that runs 4 times and i have a button on that form i want when i click the button i get the data that is input by the user in richtextarea and assigned the data of area to label and the 4 options to the radiobuttons that will be in a group box may be now  you can got my point thanks again

Comment: Oh got it, when you use the .Zip, you should do it against the list of rich text box user inputs and a 2d array of buttons per question. It would look something like:

foreach(var questionPair in zippedList)
{

    foreach(var radioButton in questionPair.RadioButtons)
    {
        radioButton.Text = questionPair.RichTextBoxText.Text;
    }
}

Comment: means no need of using for loop only foreach will solve the problem and want to confirm that 2 d array for question and for each option also??im right you really want to say that?

Comment: foreach is a loop. Just more convenient than for loops. a 2d array containing the 4 options for each question would be an easy way to get around this problem. Personally I think it might be better however to create a class with the 4 options as properties, but a 2d array would be better to visualize the problem. This problem should be diagrammed for a better understanding if you're getting confused